# Rowwise comparison of the length of a string against a list of string lengths

Tags: r

Consider the following data frame with two columns of strings of variable length:

```
library("tidyverse")

df <- tibble(REF = c("TTG", "CGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGT", "T", "TTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGT"),
             ALT = c("T", "CGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGT,CGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGT", "TTG", "TTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGT"))

# # A tibble: 4 × 2
# REF                               ALT                                                                
# <chr>                             <chr>                                                              
# 1 TTG                               T                                                                  
# 2 CGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGT CGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGT,CGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGT
# 3 T                                 TTG                                                                
# 4 TTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGT            TTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGT
```

Differently from column `REF`, column `ALT` sometimes includes several strings concatenated by comma (e.g. row 2).

I want to compare the length of strings in `REF` (`REF_LEN`) and `ALT` (`ALT_LEN`), and generate a `TYPE` column with values:

- "SNM" when `REF_LEN` = `ALT_LEN`
- "INS" when `REF_LEN` < `ALT_LEN`
- "DEL" when `REF_LEN` > `ALT_LEN`

But I want to do it in a way that, when several strings are present in `ALT`, the output of this new `TYPE` column contains these types as well separated by a comma. i.e., the expected output here would be:

```
"DEL"     "INS,DEL" "INS"     "INS"
```

So far, I know how to get the length of values in `ALT`, but I fail at collapsing these values, as the output will contain lengths from all `ALT`s in the table, not just pairwise (i.e. `1,35,31,3,24`):

```
df %>%
  dplyr::mutate(REF_LEN = str_length(REF),
                ALT_LEN = str_split(ALT, ","),
                ALT_LEN = purrr::map(ALT_LEN, str_length) %>% unlist() %>% paste(collapse = ","))
```

Code above is incomplete as you can see, but I am also unable to work in a different direction using a helper function that gets the `TYPE` column above done. This will return many errors, but not sure why, since it seems to work nicely with values from `ALT_LEN` individually:

```
name <- function(alt_lens, ref_len) {
  alt_lens <- unlist(alt_lens)
  ifelse(alt_lens < ref_len, "DEL", ifelse(alt_lens > ref_len, "INS", "SNM"))
}

df %>%
  dplyr::mutate(REF_LEN = str_length(REF),
                ALT_LEN = str_split(ALT, ","),
                TYPE = purrr::map(ALT_LEN, str_length) %>% name(REF_LEN))
```

Any ideas? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** Removed first answer. Thanks to akrun for pointing me there!. The concept is the same: using `nchar` with `case_when`, the difference is to use `separate_rows` from `tidyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  separate_rows(ALT, sep = ",") %>% 
  mutate(TYPE = case_when(nchar(REF)==nchar(ALT) ~ "SNM",
                             nchar(REF)< nchar(ALT) ~ "INS",
                             nchar(REF)> nchar(ALT) ~ "DEL",
                             TRUE ~ NA_character_)) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(TYPE = toString(TYPE)) %>% 
  slice(1)
```

```
 REF                               ALT                                    id TYPE    
  <chr>                             <chr>                               <int> <chr>   
1 TTG                               T                                       1 DEL     
2 CGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGT CGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGT     2 INS, DEL
3 T                                 TTG                                     3 INS     
4 TTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGT            TTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGT                4 INS
```

Comment: Perhaps you need `separate_rows` as well i.e. `df %>% mutate(rn= row_number()) %>% separate_rows(ALT, sep = ",") %>% mutate(TYPE = case_when(str_length(REF) == str_length(ALT) ~ "SNM", str_length(REF) < str_length(ALT) ~ "INS", TRUE ~ "DEL")) %>% group_by(rn) %>% summarise(TYPE = toString(TYPE), .groups = 'drop') %>% select(-rn) %>% bind_cols(df, .)`

Comment: @akrun 's comment worked for me, but not the solution posted here, since it does not take into account rows with more than one string (comma-separated).

Comment: Maybe the answer could be edited to include `separate_rows`? thinking that way it could be more visible that way and reach other people that might be interested in this.

Comment: @TarJae Please update your already good answer.  It just needs a single step with separate_rows and then it is just group by paste

Comment: Thank you all for your patience. I have now updated.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a codegolf-ish base R solution :

```r
df <- data.frame(REF = c("TTG", "CGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGT", "T", "TTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGT"),
             ALT = c("T", "CGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGT,CGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGT", "TTG", "TTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGT"))

df$TYPE <- mapply(
  function(x, y) paste(c("INS", "SNM", "DEL")[2 + sign(nchar(x)- nchar(y))], collapse = ","), 
  df$REF, strsplit(df$ALT, ","), USE.NAMES = FALSE)

df$TYPE
#> [1] "DEL"     "INS,DEL" "INS"     "INS"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>